# All checkboxes are being ticked after ticking only one in docusign

Tags: c#, html, docusignapi

I am using C# and the DocuSign API to generate PDF documents for users to sign through DocuSign.

I have had to implement checkbox fields into my template, here is an example

`<div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; align-self: center; border-radius: 15px; border: #565F58 1px solid; background-color: #fff;">/cb21/</div>`

Each identifier for a checkbox starts with /cb_/, the _ is replaced by a number going from 1 - 21 (21 checkboxes in total). This is how these checkboxes are created:

```cs
List<Checkbox> checkBoxes = new List<Checkbox>();

for (int index = 1; index <= 21; index++)
{
  var clickCheckboxHere = new Checkbox
  {
    AnchorString = $"/cb{index}/", //for the multiple checkboxes
    AnchorUnits = "pixels",
    AnchorYOffset = "",
    AnchorXOffset = "",
    TabGroupLabels = new List<string>() { $"checkBox{index}" },
    Shared = "false",
  };

  checkBoxes.Add(clickCheckboxHere);
}
```

As you can see the Anchor Strings are all different to each other, so technically shouldn't be linked together.

This is how the checkboxes look on the template (I have made the cb identifiers black so we can see where the checkboxes are being added and that theyre all different labels)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuPPf.png)

Is there any way that I can make it so that only one of them is checked when I click one? I've been looking for ages and cant seem to find why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get them to be checked individually, you need to set a separate TabLabel. I wasn't setting either which was causing them to be recognised as the same. this is what I added to the function:

```
TabLabel = $"checkBox{index}",
```

After adding this, I am now able to individually tick checkboxes.

Comment: You only need TabLabel, TabId is not needed